# Multiple web sites on single Windows Azure Web Sites instance

Tags: azure

Is it possible to host multiple websites with different domain names on a single Azure Web Sites instance in shared or standard mode? If so, how does one go about doing this?

E.g., in my test instance, all requests are served up from the "site\wwwroot" directory. I would like to be able to have example.com served up from "site\example.com" and example.org served up from "site\example.org", but I don't see a way to set this up from within the online Azure management GUI. I can add both domains via "Manage Domains", but I don't see a way to have them serve out different sets of files.

Note that there are several discussions here and elsewhere about hosting multiple sites on a single Azure *Cloud Services* instance, but I am specifically inquiring about doing so on an Azure *Web Sites* instance.

Comment: From the documents and slides MS provided it's said it's possible to host more than one web site in standard mode. But I didn't try it.

Comment: Note that if you use Standard, you can create additional sites with no additional cost. That would seem much simpler than trying to re-use a single site for everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first you create multiple azurewebsites. Then take on AzureWebsite say site1 and then configure it for Standard mode. while configuring select all other sites in the dropdown as shown  below - 
[image]

This will make all selected sites to be on that standard mode and share resources on dedicated instance.

Now to configure custom DNS for each and every site, you can do that individually for every site on Azure management portal UI. Then Azure is going to take care of mappings and will ensure that right sites will be served for right domains.