# Azure Website with multiple Sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Seems really stupid by I just can't find it:

The web portal seems not very intuitive, how do I pay for one "Website" and run up to 500 sites in it? I suppose when I add a "Website" by clicking the plus in the bottom left corner, I add a whole VM instead of a sub-site. How to add just a sub-site?

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/

**UPDATE**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011047/multiple-web-sites-on-single-windows-azure-web-sites-instance) clarifies it with a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scale your site to Standard, Web Sites will migrate you to your own VM. All of the other Web Sites deployed to that region can be added to that standard instance and thus a single VM which holds up to 500 sites.

The clarifying point is that you still have 500 sites provisioned in Azure, they would just all reside in the single VM which was provisioned by the Web Sites infrastructure.

Comment: So it's automatically added to the same VM? Does that mean I can even add node.js or whatever and it runs on the same Windows VM than my first application which is .NET? There's no indication that new Web Sites are added to the same standard instance I'm paying for.

Comment: The indication is that when you create a new site in the same region it who in `Standard`mode by default on portal. Also when you go to the scale tab on any of the Standard sites you will see a list of all the sites running on the same VM. You can run any type of application you want (.NET, node.js, PHP, Python, etc) on any type of site whether it's Free, Shared, or Standard. There are no limitation on what stack you can use.

Comment: You might want to review this post by Daria Grigoriu from the Windows Azure Web Sites team for more information on the [development stacks in Windows Azure Web Sites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/01/10/windows-azure-websites-development-stacks-support.aspx)