# Host 2 separate sites, one domain, on one Azure site

Tags: azure

I have a wordpress site hosted on Azure. Call it, mysite.com. I'd also like to develop a separate .net app and host it at subsite.mysite.com. How can I do this without having to pay for 2 separate Azure sites?

Comment: you could look at [Multiple web sites on single Windows Azure Web Sites instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011047/multiple-web-sites-on-single-windows-azure-web-sites-instance) for detailed info.

Comment: I saw that but i suspect that the info is outdated, can't find anything like that in the interface. But I could be wrong

Comment: Try it by using virtua hosting over apache

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to achieve what you require. However, key point here is to understand the [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/). Because, in Azure app service, you never **pay** (your concern is having to pay, not having to maintain) for a single site!

If you take a closer look at the [App Service Pricing model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/), you will see that even with the **free** (like in **Free lunch**) tier, you get to host 10 applications in your hosting plan. But you need custom domain, then you go to Shared plan, you already can host 100 web sites within it, all with your custom domain/s.

Next you will have to learn a bit about what is [Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), what is [Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name), what is [Sub Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain), what is [A DNS Record and what is C-Name DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types), because these are all thing you need to understand in order to properly configure your sites.

And finally read the [article on how to configure custom domain for Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).

**Remember**. With Azure App Service, you are paying for a **hosting environment** (or service plan), not for a single web site!

Comment: With shared, you pay for each site! Check your own link on the pricing. With 5 shared sites it's better to move to 1 standard